# How to import data from multiple text files on a folder, starting on line 20, while adding the current file name on the first column using excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

i'm new to stackoverflow and a newbie programmer, hope i'm asking my question in the right way and place so i can get some help.
Here is the problem:

I have a folder c:/SENSOR/ which contains multiple files named "LANCE 60.txt", "LANCE 61.txt", "LANCE 62.txt" and so on...

Each file is formatted like this:

EXAMPLE:

```
#B  Created:    18.02.2017 08:10:14
#5  Field separation:   0
#2  Date & Time:    1
#6  Decimal point:  ,
#7  Date def.:  dd.mm.yyyy  .
#8  Time def.:  :
##  Axis    0   Temperature(°C) clRed   FALSE
##  Axis    1   Depth(m)    clBlue  TRUE
##  Axis    2   Salinity(psu)   clGreen FALSE
##  Axis    3   Conductivity(mS/cm) $00FF80FF   FALSE
##  Axis    4   Sound Velocity(m/sec)   $00404080   FALSE
##  Series  0   Temp(°C)    clRed   0   Temp(°C)    2
##  Series  1   Depth(m)    clBlue  1   Depth(m)    2
##  Series  2   Salinity(psu)   clGreen 2   Salinity(psu)   2
##  Series  3   Conduct(mS/cm)  $00FF80FF   3   Conduct(mS/cm)  2
##  Series  4   Sound Velocity(m/sec)   $00404080   4   Velocity(m/sec) 2
##  Recorder    10  DST CTD 8771
##  Chart   10S8771DAT  
#D  Data:   248 16.02.2017 14:50:00 18.02.2017 08:00:00
1   16.02.2017 14:50:00 22,60   8,65    0,00    0,00    1489,74
2   16.02.2017 15:00:00 8,61    77,46   31,24   33,24   1481,28
3   16.02.2017 15:10:00 5,66    244,84  31,53   31,09   1472,82
4   16.02.2017 15:20:00 5,22    415,69  31,59   30,86   1473,94
5   16.02.2017 15:30:00 4,75    586,96  31,64   30,58   1474,88
6   16.02.2017 15:40:00 4,42    755,45  31,61   30,35   1476,25 
...
```

I need to add all files in only one excel sheet (skipping the first 19 lines which contain info I don't need at all, and staring at line 20 when the data actually begins) but i need to firstly remove the line number from each line of the input and instead include the TXT file name to the first column on the resulting sheet.

So as to get a sheet that looks like this:

```
File name | Date | Time | Temp | Depth | Salinity | Conductivity | Speed |
```

I've borrowed some code from a similar question, and modified it to my purpose... 
I've managed so far to begin at line 20, remove the line numbers of each file, and add file after file to the sheet, but i have found no way of including the file name on the first column.

```
Sub Sample()

Dim myfiles
Dim i As Integer

myfiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="TXT Files (*.txt), 
*.txt", MultiSelect:=True)

If Not IsEmpty(myfiles) Then
    For i = LBound(myfiles) To UBound(myfiles)
         With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _"TEXT;" & myfiles(i), Destination:=Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0))
            .Name = "Sample"
            .FieldNames = False
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 437
            .TextFileStartRow = 20
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(xlSkipColumn, xlDMYFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat)
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .TextFileThousandsSeparator = " "
            .TextFileDecimalSeparator = ","
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
     Next i
Else
    MsgBox "No File Selected"
End If

End Sub
```

(also i would prefer the code to instead of asking what files to read and from where, just used the path "C:\SENSOR\" automatically)

If anyone can offer any help, it would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: If you don't want the dialog you can hard code the file name value like myfiles = "C:\SENSOR*.txt" but I think you may run into an issue if there is more than one file in the folder.

Comment: there folder has tons of files!

Comment: Might want to keep the file prompt then unless you want to also code the loop through them all!

Comment: OK! will do, any thoughts on adding the filename?

Comment: You should be able to add your myfiles variable as another column on the Array.

Comment: I'm pretty new to all this, wouldn't know how to go about it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to modify this.

Your text files are not properly delimited.  So I split them with a space, and then put them into a tab delimited array in order to write them to a 7 column range.  Try this on a blank sheet and see if it works for you.  It works ok for me.

```
Sub readWrite()
Dim fileNum As Integer, dataLine As String, arrayCounter As Long, mySplitArray, tempSplit

Dim myfiles, fileName As String
Dim i As Integer, myArray()

arrayCounter = 0
ReDim myArray(1 To 1)
myfiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="TXT Files (*.txt), *.txt", MultiSelect:=True)

If Not IsEmpty(myfiles) Then
    For i = LBound(myfiles) To UBound(myfiles)
        fileName = myfiles(i)
        tempSplit = Split(fileName, "\")
        fileName = tempSplit(UBound(tempSplit))
        fileNum = FreeFile()
        Open myfiles(i) For Input As #fileNum
        While Not EOF(fileNum)
            Line Input #fileNum, dataLine
            If left(dataLine, 1) <> "#" Then
                arrayCounter = arrayCounter + 1
                ReDim Preserve myArray(1 To arrayCounter)
                myArray(arrayCounter) = fileName & " " & dataLine
            End If
        Wend


        For k = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
            myString = ""
            mySplitArray = Split(myArray(k), " ")
            For j = LBound(mySplitArray) To UBound(mySplitArray)
                If mySplitArray(j) <> "" Then
                    If j = 0 Then
                        myString = myString & mySplitArray(j) & " " & mySplitArray(j + 1)
                    Else
                        If j <> 1 And j <> 2 Then
                            myString = myString & vbTab & mySplitArray(j)
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next j
            Range("A" & k & ":H" & k) = Split(myString, vbTab)
'            Debug.Print myString
        Next k
        Close fileNum
    Next i
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow! thanks John! that almost does it... there's a couple of problems though:
on the first column i need only the file name (no path, no file extension) and i'm loosing the date :(
Plus its adding a column that gets filled with "#N/A"
example output line:
    C:\SENSOR\LANCE 138.txt 14:50:00 22,60 8,65 0,00 0,00 1489,74 #N/A

Comment: I had to modify the above answer to delete the single digit and replace it with the file name.

Comment: I changed it again so it should only show the filename now, not the path.

Comment: Of course this code is dependant on the structure of your example text file.  If that structure changes then the code may not work and you'll have to modify it.  But as long as your text files are in that same format you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: (all files have the same structure)
Now i'm getting different problems.
example output lines: 

LANCE 1 16.02.2017   14:50:00 22,60    8,65 0,00    0,00
LANCE 2 16.02.2017 15:00:00 8,61      77,46 31,24  33,24

so the file name is missing the identifier (they are all called "LANCE" instead of "LANCE 01", "LANCE 02"....

the second column keeps the line number of the input.

i'm mising the last column of data "speed"

Comment: don't know if that was clear enough, let me try again:
i'm getting:
incomple file name | line number (from input) | Date | Time | Temp | Depth | Salinity | Conductivity | 

and no Speed.

Comment: Yes.  That is because there is a space in your file names.  I'll work it out.  Might not be until 2morrow though.

Comment: When ever you can John! to tell you the truth your code just makes me dizzy! there is so much i need to learn yet! So many functions and objects i didn't knew about. I'll be waiting and keep trying to understand your code in the mean while ;). Thanks for your help!

Comment: I updated it again to get your full file name.  The script splits by spaces into one array, so it split your file name into two parts.  Then it put them in a tab delimited array file which is good for putting the members into a range on the worksheeet.  So when something is not working it is just a matter of tweaking the array numbers.  It should work now.

Comment: I'm still trying to make sense of it all! i'm sorry to be quite so persistant, but as i said im a newbie....
so now the first column is all right, just the file name, but there still are problems:
(i added the "|" characters to make it easier to read) 
example output line: 
LANCE 60.txt | 14:50:00 | 22,60 | 8,65 | 0,00 | 0,00 | 1489,74 | #N/A
So there is no date which should be the first value after de file name, and i'm getting a last column that gets "#N/A" values

Comment: So i finally got it! Thank you so much John!!
I had to change a bit the if statements inside
the For j = LBound(mySplitArray) To UBound(mySplitArray) loop!

Comment: Good.  I've found it helps to first define your desired steps in quasi-code.  You did that with your question.  You have x format txt file and  want all lines except those that start with "#" to be spaced out over a 7 column range.  The other lines don't have a specific delimiter, but elements are separated by at least one space or more.  So separate the elements into an array. Put only the non-empty elements into another tab delimited array and put it on the sheet.  Sometimes you cant see trees for the forest but you can follow the code to see that was the objective.

Comment: It took me a while since it was the first time i have worked with arrays in vba, but i finally got the logic behind it all. Again i thank you, besides solving my problem i learned a lot!